# Creating new users in quickblox not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, quickblox

I have been trying to create users on quickblox without any success. I have reviewed their documentation and have searched the internet, including SO, to no avail. Below is my code:

```
var QB = require('quickblox');

//Inizializing quickblox
QB.init(6455, "7j9XXXXXXXX", "DdWCXXXXXXX");
QB.createSession(function(err, result) {
    // callback function
    console.log('Callback', err, result);//This display 'Callback null undefine'            
});

var params = { 'login': 'displayName', 'password': 'userIdert'};
QB.users.create(params, function(err, user) {
   if (user) 
   {
       console.log('Sign Up SUCCESS: ', JSON.stringify(user));
   } else  {
       console.log('Sign Up ERROR: ', JSON.stringify(err));
   }
});
```

PS:
I used this to install quickblox in nodejs: `npm install quickblox --save`

**What I've tried**

1. Tried to output the result gotten from `createSession()` it return null for error and undefine for result
2. Added `QB.users.create()` inside the callback function
3. Use qbuserparam with `createSession()`

Comment: The entire second half, starting with setting the `params`, has to go into the callback. Also: are you getting an error message? If so, which one?

Comment: @Chris, I tried that also it doesn't work. No error it returns null I commented that in the code I uploaded above

Comment: telling us it "doesn't work" is completely useless; we already know that. You need to do basic troubleshooting and tell us how stuff fails and what errors you're getting. If the callback's `err` is `null`, that's a good thing. You said you already moved the rest of the code into the callback; can you the question accordingly?

Comment: Thanks, Chris I just updated my post